# How to SELECT items from from an array (IN clause details)?

Tags: java, sql, select, jdbc, ibatis

I would like to do something in Java (using iBatis, JDBC, etc., really in SQL) like:

```
SELECT SUM(rowName) FROM myTable WHERE id = [myArrayOfIds]
```

Where myArrayOfIds can be almost any length. Now I know you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(rowName) FROM myTable WHERE id IN (x, y, z)
```

but what happens for longer lists? For example my list could be as little as a few items to hundreds or more items. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on your flavour of SQL.  For instance, Oracle does not allow more than 1000 values in an `IN()` list.  Other flavours may vary.

Answer (score 1):

one alternative would be to insert those ids to a table, then do a join

```
SELECT SUM(rowName) FROM myTable ta inner join tempTable tb on ta.id = tb.id
```

Comment: it's still the same problem, you've just moved the array (IN) to the insert command.

Comment: you can't do inserts using "in", but you can build a batch of statements within a transaction

Comment: I'd say, test first to see if the performance is actually bad, I have done similar select statements using "in" and the performance is good enough that I don't have to try other alternatives

Comment: batching is great if you can do it at set times, but as part of a normal day to day usage, you wouldn't want to do that on a system. Generally when you're doing updates it's based on user interaction, to which I wouldn't recommend the use of batching...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle definitely allows more than 1000 items in the `IN` clause.  It's your persistence tool that is limiting this.  `iBatis` or Hibernate, whatever.  Use Oracle Sqlplus and you'll see this is not an Oracle limit.

[Suggestion from BlackTigerX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1498968/102067) would work, or you could call the query multiple times, passing 1000 items at a time and aggregating the results.  Either way, you're just working around your persistence tool limitation.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Oracle allows a maximum of 1000 values in the in clause.